# Where do i start in making an android app?

Tags: android

So I'm new to programming and I really want to get into the deep stuffs. So firstly I'm looking to make an android app but I really don't know where to even begin. Which framework do i use? What programming language should I master. I just need a little light to be shed here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Programming Language, you can learn **Java** or **Kotlin** .. Etc

For **Java**, use **NetBeans** to train and improve, I really recommend it for beginners.

https://netbeans.org

After you learn programming language, start learning Android development. 
You will need **Android studio**

https://developer.android.com/studio

You also need to learn **SQLite** for databases. 
Wish this helps.

Comment: Thanks I think this will be very helpful